# When does preempt_count() & PREEMPT_ACTIVE == 0?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, scheduler, preemption

I am looking at scheduler code in Linux:

```c
if (prev->state && !(preempt_count() & PREEMPT_ACTIVE)) {
    if (unlikely(signal_pending_state(prev->state, prev))) {
        prev->state = TASK_RUNNING;
    } else {
        deactivate_task(rq, prev, DEQUEUE_SLEEP);
        prev->on_rq = 0;
```

As I understand, if the `prev` task is uninterruptible, this code will deactivate the task (and remove from runqueue) provided

```
preempt_count() & PREEMPT_ACTIVE == 0
```

Can someone explain to me what is `preempt_count` in `thread_info` for and when will this condition met or not?

Comment: preempt_counts upper bits are used for things like IRQ counts, one of the bits is used to signal if PREEMPT is active, which is what the line is checking for.

Comment: But I thought schedule() couldn't be called in IRQ handler as schedule can sleep. (You are only preempted by interrupt right? Otherwise you would be schedule out right?)

Answer (score 1):

`preempt_count` is the counter used by `preempt_disable()` and `preempt_enable()`, which enables their nested use. Higher order bits of `preempt_count` are used for hardirq and softirq counters, an NMI bit and a `PREEMPT_ACTIVE` bit. These are defined in `include/linux/preempt_mask.h`. In x86 architectures a `PREEMPT_NEED_RESCHED` bit is also used in `preempt_count`, for optimization of deciding to reschedule.

Now, I am not clear on the exact *need* for the `PREEMPT_ACTIVE` bit in `preempt_count`. In kernel version 3.17, which I have worked on, `PREEMPT_ACTIVE` is set in `preempt_count` exactly before calling `__schedule()` and reset immediately after the call, in all cases, except when it is called from `schedule()`. This would mean, inside `__schedule()`, `PREEMPT_ACTIVE` is set in `preempt_count`, when `__schedule()` was called because of kernel preemption, i.e., not intentionally for some other OS functionality, which would use `schedule()`. What would such "other OS functionality" be varies, depending on whether you build the kernel with `CONFIG_PREEMPT`, `CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY`, or `CONFIG_PREEMPT_NONE`, but it includes explicit blocking on a mutex.